# Overriding CSS style

Tags: css

I have a CSS in a third party css file:

```
.gallery li > a{
    background-image:url(images/loading.gif);
}
```

I want to override this so that a different background image is used instead.  I have achieved this by using an inline style on the a tag itself and this works but I don't like inline styles.

I don't want to change the third party css file in case we one day use an updated version of the css file and lose our changes.  I added a new CSS class on the a tag itself and put my new background-image css in a new css file associated with the new css class.  For some reason this does not work.  Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Did you try using the same selector and loading the third party css before yours, so it overrides the third party css?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by same selector?  I didn't know that I had to load my cSS before the other one - this I will try thanks.

Comment: If the same selector `.gallery li > a` is encountered after it appears once, its overwritten. archil's answer is more elegant though

Comment: What do the relevant lines of code in the new CSS file look like? And: is the new CSS file loaded *after* the other file?

Comment: I tried loading the new file before and after - neither way worked.  the new file contains only this: .gallery li > a.documentLink {
    background-image: url(/Content/css/img/Document-icon.png);
}

Comment: it's ok it all works now - silly mistake on my part :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying higher priority css selector than old one should help

```
.gallery li > a.my-custom-class {
    background-image:url(myCustomImage);
}
```

Comment: or alternatively (e.g. if you didn't have a custom class) put a `!important` behind each property in the specification. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: I tried using important but that didn't work either.  By the way atchil.  I tried this and it doesn't work.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can I send it to you somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Creat your custom class in your new CSS file and use this one may it'll help you

```
.myClass {background-image:(image/path.png) !important;}
```

Comment: I think you can try out this for important, are you tried like this?